# Fallback system doesn't look in default

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, theme-fallback

I have something weird going on in my Magento 1.9.2.4 environment. I'm creating a new theme for different shops. This is what is looks like:

```
-package
--- default
--- theme1
--- theme2
--- theme3
```

I have theme1 set for my first store. In the skin I have some files in `default/fonts` and I **don't** have a fonts map with files in the skin of my theme1. Because of this, I expect my Magento to look in `package/default`, but it doesn't. In the console, it gives me the error that `skin/frontend/package/theme1/fonts/specificfile.woff` is missing.

Why doesn't it look in my `theme1/default` folder and how do I make this happen?

**Edit:** To be clear, I do have files in my `app/design/frontend/package/default` folder, so it's supposed to see this as a theme

Comment: How is your code adding this font file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have css file in theme1, him is call font in current theme and you must copy font in theme1

See example below source font go back with a folder and enter the folder fonts and font if you can call it there

```
@font-face {
    font-family: yourFont;
    src: url(../fonts/font.woff);
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, this had nothing to do with the fallback structure.. I simply had the wrong path entered in my CSS. Thank you for giving me the tip.